# Show that $S(x, t)$ Is a Tempered Distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition

We were given the expression $\hat S(\xi, t) = e^{\, i|\xi|^2t}$, where $\xi \in \mathbb R^n$.  If my calculation is correct, after the reverse Fourier transform, we have:
$$S(x, t) = \left( \frac{i}{2t} \right)^{n/2} e^{\, \frac{-i|x|^2}{4t}}$$
Anyway, a tempered distribution is a continuous linear functional on the Schwartz space, but to me, $S(x, t)$ is just some function except when $t = 0$.  So, how does $S(x, t)$ act on a test function?

Furthermore, how does this related to the $H^s$ spaces and their duals?

\begin{align}
H^s & = \left\{ \, u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n) : (1 + |\xi|^2)^{s/2} \hat u(\xi) \in L^2(\mathbb R^n) \, \right\} \\
& = \left\{ \, u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n) : D^\alpha(u) \in L^2(\mathbb R^n) \text{ where } |\alpha| < s \, \right\}
\end{align}

Thanks for the help.  I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that every tempered distribution has a Fourier transform defined by 
$$
<\hat{T},\varphi> = <T,\hat{\varphi}>.
$$
Similarly, we can define the inverse Fourier transform of any tempered distribution.  Consequently, it suffices to prove that your "transformed" function $\hat{S}$ is a tempered distribution.  Since it is actually a smooth and bounded function its action as a tempered distribution is just integration, i.e. it's the map $T_t$ given by 
$$
<T_t,\psi> = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \hat{S}(\xi,t) \psi(\xi) d\xi,
$$
which it's not too hard to show is actually a tempered distribution.  Once you have this then you can just do your computation to get the formula for the action of $S$, the inverse Fourier transform.